# VB Open Browser Window Forms Application

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2008

Windows forms application. How can I open browser window with specific url on click of a button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Click handler use:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.com")
```

That will open a URL in whatever the user's default browser is.